# Transfer function names from one IDA DB to another

Tags: ida, code-modeling

Do anyone know about an automatic way to transfer function names from one IDA file to another while:

1. First IDA file is based on version 1 of the executable.
2. Second IDA file is based on the updated, version 2, of the same executable.

I'm aware of Zynamics BinDiff. I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: FYI in "Tools to work cooperatively on the same binary" there are only tools list, but no explicit information regarding the asked question. If you think differently, please point where specifically in the "Tools to work cooperatively on the same binary" there is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MyNav](http://mynav.googlecode.com). In [this video](https://www.hex-rays.com/contests/2010/MyNav/tutorials/exportimport.htm) you can check how it can be done with this tool.

Comment: Hello Joxean Koret,

could you update your plugin https://github.com/joxeankoret/mynav to make it work in IDA 7.x. Because currently it doesn't run:

mynav.py: undefined function __plugins__mynav.PLUGIN_ENTRY

Comment: There is no need anymore to use MyNav as almost every part of the functionality is integrated into IDA, especially the Differential Debugging part. Actually, I added it myself. Take a look to [this](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/replayer/trace_replayer.pdf). If what you want is to port symbols, use Diaphora (https://github.com/joxeankoret/diaphora) or YaDiff.

Comment: I need to transfer symbols from one IDA database into another IDA database with the same module. I have IDA database for the exe file and a crash dump which I load to IDA. So I would like to load symbols for that exe, which I already reversed in a separated database into crash dump analysis in another IDA. Seems like diaphora can't do that: diaphora_import.py just loads structures, not the function names. :(

Comment: You need to export both databases and diff them... Take a look to this blog: http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=271

Comment: so I can't just simply move the names, I need to export all the assembler instructions and meta and then make a diff just to transfer the names... For 300 mb idb file just exporting to sqlite takes 30 minutes.

Comment: You have various options: 1) Export only function summaries with Diaphora (https://github.com/joxeankoret/diaphora/wiki/Diaphora-takes-too-long-exporting!#exporting-only-function-summaries) 2) Dump the database to IDC (File -> Produce File -> Dump Database to IDC). 3) Write a script for doing whatever you want for your usecase.